# Getting error using KinectRegion in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

I am very familiar with .net but am new to XAML. I have built a Kinect application that recognizes a users wave and takes a photo. The problem is now I am trying to recognize the user hovering over a KinectTileButton so I can upload that image to a social network.

I have ran the demo ControlsBasics WPF and everything works correctly. I have tried to move the code over, even created a new project and still am getting the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls.KinectRegion' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '36' and line position '10'.
```

I get the exception when `this.InitializeComponent();` is executed. I can't for the life of me figure out why I am getting this, I have compared every property in each project and cant find the issue. Hoping someone has had this problem before or its so easy I missed it..

Here is some of the XAML:

```
<Grid>
<k:KinectRegion Grid.Row="1" x:Name="kinectRegion">
        <Grid x:Name="kinectRegionGrid" Margin="10,20,10,20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="170" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <k:KinectScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" k:KinectTileButton.Click="KinectTileButtonClick">
                    <!-- items for design layout.  They will be replaced at runtime. -->
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="1"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="2"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="3"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="4"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="5"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="6"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="7"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="8"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="9"/>
                    <k:KinectTileButton Label="10"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </k:KinectScrollViewer>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <k:KinectTileButton Grid.Column="0" Label="1"  Click="PageRightButtonClick" />
                <k:KinectTileButton Grid.Column="2" Label="2"  Click="PageRightButtonClick" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </k:KinectRegion>
```

Comment: what happens when you step thru the code.. also what does the actual code look like on line `36` we can't see line numbers in the code that you posted.. thanks

Comment: look at the InnerException.. 10-1 odds are you have an Object not being set to an Instance properly..

Comment: Trying to step through it just blows up on `this.InitializeComponent();` The line numbers in the exception don't really help at all.

Comment: If I comment out the KinectRegion it works just fine.

Comment: sounds like you have a reference issue or perhaps you should step over the initializeComponent(); code.. it's hard to see what the heck you're doing with out seeing the codebehind.. have a good weekend i'm out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrapped a try catch around the `this.InitializeComponent();` and was able to see the inner exception. Looks like I was missing the Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Interaction dll.

Thanks